# PostGIS - Get a point inside a line or polygon

Tags: postgis, polygon, linestring, centroids

I need to get the center point of a line or polygon to make `marker` for my app. So that when you click a marker the geometry appears (line or polygon). I used `ST_Centroid` to make it work.

The result is what I expected unnest some polygons or lines whichs centroids are out of the geometry. What i would like for those lines or polygons is to get the "most center point" but inside the geometry.

**How can I do this? Is there a solution?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the doc: [ST_PointOnSurface](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_PointOnSurface.html) — Returns a POINT guaranteed to lie on the surface.

Comment: For lines ST_LineInterpolatePoint with fraction 0.5 should be perfect http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/ST_LineInterpolatePoint.html

Comment: ST_PointOnSurface() works with Lines ! (thx Postgis)

Comment: Yes! You're right @user30184 because it seems that for lines ST_PointOnSurface() takes a point arbitrary, i'm not sure but in doc example takes the first point of a LineString.

Answer (score 8):

In my case I have each geometry in disctint tables. What I did was :

1. **For lines** -> `ST_LineInterpolatePoint()` with 0.5 factor.
2. **For polygons** -> Test if `ST_Centroid()` is inside its geometry. If so, `ST_Centroid()` is the best choice, if not I choose `PointOnSurface()`.

Here's the query :

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN (SELECT the_geom FROM points WHERE gid = d.gid) IS NOT NULL
    THEN (SELECT the_geom FROM points WHERE gid = d.gid)
    WHEN (SELECT the_geom FROM lines WHERE gid = d.gid) IS NOT NULL
    THEN ST_LineInterpolatePoint((SELECT the_geom FROM lines WHERE gid = d.gid), 0.5)
    WHEN (SELECT the_geom FROM polygons WHERE gid = d.gid AND ST_Intersects(ST_Centroid(the_geom),the_geom)) IS NOT NULL
    THEN ST_Centroid((SELECT the_geom FROM polygons WHERE gid = d.gid))
    ELSE ST_PointOnSurface((SELECT the_geom FROM polygons WHERE gid = d.gid))
    END AS center
FROM someTable d
```

Comment: && operator checks only bbox. You may want to use ST_intersects().

Comment: You're right. I was wrong. I'll update my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In the @Jose 's answer, instead of intersect we should use contains and in when condition we should use Boolean validation

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN (ST_Contains(the_geom, ST_Centroid(the_geom))) IS TRUE
       THEN ST_Centroid(the_geom)
       ELSE ST_PointOnSurface(the_geom)
    END AS center
FROM someTable
```